# EncryptedCookie gem causes TypeError in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, rack, thin

I'm trying to make my Sinatra app's sessions more secure, and to do that I'd like to use the EncryptedCookie gem.  Unfortunately, when I visit any page in my app, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /
no _dump_data is defined for class UnboundMethod
file: encrypted_cookie.rb location: dump line: 68
```

Here's my code:

```
configure do
  use Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie,
   :key => 'myapp.session',
   :domain => 'myapp.com',
   :path => '/',
   :expire_after => 1200,
   :secret => 'bigcrazysecretstringhere'
end
```

I tried using the EncryptedCookie gem with the same settings as shown above in a simple Sinatra app I made to test the gem, and it worked fine.  There must be some other setting in my app that's interfering with the app, but I can't figure out what it might be. Has anyone out there experienced a similar issue?

(I've also tried starting the app with 'thin start', 'rackup config.ru', and 'ruby myapp.rb'- none of these made a difference.)

Comment: Did you delete any old cookies from the site before you enabled encryption?  Maybe it's trying to decrypt plaintext and getting sad?

Comment: The code you've provided looks fine, the only thing I do differently is put the use statement in the Rack part of my app (usually in the `config.ru`) as it will get loaded before the Sinatra app. Since it mentions _dump_data, have you [set this to `false`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#dumperrors---log-exception-backtraces-to-stderr).

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against the wall for well over a week, I discovered the contractor who worked on the project before me had put

```
use Rack::Session::Pool
```

200 lines below the original

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie
```

I removed that and Encrypted Cookie worked fine.  Lesson learned:  Immediately abstract away everything you can when handed a 500 line Sinatra app.  Then things can't hide from you.